# Using Generics in TypeScript with LocalStorage Service - Angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

Trying to comeup with the service to use local storage. Little new to typescript so need help with generics part here. Don't want to use a third-party package since my requirement is very simple. I can put any data like string, number, date, boolean or my object in local storage and retrieve it as well. I want this service to handle every thing for me.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class LocalStorageService {
  constructor() { }

  clear() {
    localStorage.clear();
  }

  removeItem(key: string) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }

  setItem<T>(key: string, data: T): boolean {
    try {
      if (typeof data === "string") {
        localStorage.setItem(key, data)
      }
      else if (typeof data === "number" || typeof data === "boolean" || typeof data === "date") {
        localStorage.setItem(key, data.toString())
      }
      else {
        //its my custom object
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
      }
      return true;
    }
    catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  getItem<T>(key: string) : T {
    try {
      let data: object = null;
      if (typeof T === "string" || typeof T === "number" || typeof T === "boolean" || typeof T === "date") {
        data = <T>localStorage.getItem(key);
      }
      else {
        data = <T>JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
      }

      if (data && data is T) {
        return <T>data;
      }

      return null;

    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error getting data from localStorage', e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

In the set method, `typeof data === "date"` is resulting in `=== cannot be applied to strings, boolean, number` etc. It is only on date part.

in the get method, how to check the typeof T and then return the proper T back.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `get` method, [the type parameter `T` is not known at runtime](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure), so you can't use it to decide how to decode the item.  You'll need to either (1) pass an extra parameter to `getItem` to control the decoding or (2) use a storage format that can be decoded in the same way for all `T`.  For example, you can use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` regardless of the type, but this will not preserve dates.  Or you can use a third-party library that is like `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` but preserves dates.  The library I have experience with is Meteor's EJSON library; [this](https://github.com/primus/ejson) appears to be a standalone package of the EJSON library that you can use in a non-Meteor project.

Comment: Coming from C#/MVC and was trying to decode my getSession generic method into typescript. Trying to comeup with something that i could use for anything. Here is the C# method that i tried to follow... `public static T GetItem<T>(string key)
        {
            object item = null;
            CheckSessionAvailability();
            item = HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
            if ((item != null) && !(item is T))
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Cannot convert");
            }

            return (T)item;
        }`